# ADF V2 - MongoDB to ADLS

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-data-factory

I’m loading datas from MongoDB into Azure Data Lake Storage in JSon format, and I’m facing two issues :

- String fields are truncated, if I have a 4000 characters  value in Mongo it become a 250 characters value in my json output file.
  Is this a known behavior ? Any way to avoid this data loss ?
- Generated Json file are flattened version of my MongoDb document.
  In mongo :

[image: Mongo structure]

Json in ADLS :

```
{
             "_id": "NonConformityLine_492",
             "Id":492,
             "Code": "",
             "Label": "",
             "Type": "",
             "Comments": "",
             "DateRecorded": "",
             "Details_DeliveryAccepted": true,
             "Details_TemperatureIssueOnAllDelivery": false,
             "Details_TemperatureType": "",
             "Details_TemperatureValue": "",
             "Details_TemperatureTolerance": "",
             "IsSetOnEasyVista": false,
             "Level": 2,
             "ManufacturerCode": "n/a",
             "NonConformityReportCode": "
             "NonConformityTypeCode": "",
             "NonConformityTypeTitle": "",
             "OrderCode": "",
             "RawMaterialCode": "",
             "RecorderName": "",
             "Response_ResponseFullText": "
             "Response_ResponseDate": "”
             "Response_ResponseAuthor": "",
             "SiteOrPosCode": "",
             "Status": "",
             "SupplierCode": "",
             "WarehouseCode": ""
}
```

Any way to keep the data structure ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two limitations of ADF MongoDB connector implementation.

- String fields are truncated if it's longer than 255 currently. The default string column length is 255 as a compromise with the string data in MongoDB that will be relatively short (names, addresses, titles, etc.), and a larger value will impact performance and memory size. Later this month, ADF will expose a configuration for this issue.
- The Mongo documents getting flattened is kind of by-design currently because we were using a tabular intermediate data structure for orthogonal data transfer across M*N data stores. We did realize that this approach doesn't work well for NoSql data stores and we are improving this area. MongoDB is in the backlog list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, happy to know i'm not crazy :)